# Microsoft Translator API java

Tags: java, translation, bing-translator-api

I'm developing a web app (in java) in which the admin creates some forms.

When a user fills a form of those created by the admin, I would that he/she can see each name field translated in his/her language (when he/she does mouse over the field name).

I need a step by step tutorial or some examples to get started.

Moreover, do I need to find a java wrapper of the MS API or can I use ajax?

Comment: You can use some sort of JSON or REST wrapper. I believe I used REST when I did my iPhone App. But the MS/Azure translator API allows you to use JSON or REST. The Google Translator API is much more efficient, and cleaner than MS though. You have to pay to play though, primary difference, I think MS gives you 2000 or so free a month quota.